# My Charts.js line chart dissappers when I try to flow my data from mysql using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I'm having a issue with my charts like I stated in the title. When I try to get my data from MySQL graph disappears and I'm not getting any errors. but graph perfectly works when I'm entering them myself. What could possibly be the fault here? I'm pretty new in this so the code can be a little bit bad sorry for that in advance. Thank you.

```
<?php

include('./connection.php');

?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1.0">
                <title>Nisantasi Cafe</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grafic1.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <script>
                const labels = [
                '2022-01-01',
                '2022-02-01',
                '2022-03-01',
                '2022-04-01',
                '2022-05-01',
                '2022-06-01',
                '2022-07-01',
                '2022-08-01',
                '2022-09-01',
                '2022-10-01',
                '2022-11-01',
                '2022-12-01',
                ];
                const data = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                label: 'Bitcoin',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 255)',
                data: [<?php
                        include("/connection.php");
                        $sql = "SELECT birim_deger.karsilik, tarih.tarih FROM birim_deger, tarih_deger, tarih 
                        WHERE birim_deger.deger_id=tarih_deger.deger_id AND tarih_deger.tarih_id=tarih.tarih_id AND birim_deger.coin_id=2 AND birim_deger.itibari_id=1;";
                        
                        $result = $con->query($sql);

                        $data = array();
                        foreach($result as $row){
                        $data[] = $row;
                        }
                        print json_encode($data)
                        ?> 
                    ],
                }]
                };
                const config = {
                type: 'line',
                data: data,
                options: {}
                };
                
            </script>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fapeople-arrows"></i></span>
                                <span class="title">
                                    <h2>NCS</h2>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="admin.php">
                                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fahome"></i></span>
                                <span class="title">Ana Sayfa</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                    <a href="grafic.php">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chartline"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Broşürcü</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="grafic1.php">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chartline"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Fal Dağılımı</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="grafic2.php">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chartline"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Falcı</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="grafic3.php">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fas fachart-line"></i></span>
                            <span class="title">Toplam Fal</span>
                        </a>
                </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php">
                                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-signout-alt"></i></span>
                                <span class="title">Çıkış Yap</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="topbar">
                        <div class="toggle" onclick="toggleMenu();"></div>
                        <div class="search">
                            <label>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="chart-container" style="background:transparent;display:inline-block; text-align:center; height:90vh; width:120vh; position:absolute;left:15%;top:10%;">
                </div>
                <div class="chart-container" style="background:transparent;display:inline-block; text-align:center; height:90vh; width:120vh; position:absolute;left:5%;top:10%;">
                <div clasas="selectBox">
                    <select id="coincesit">
                        <option value="566,641,591,629">Bitcoin</option>
                        <option value="466,341,491,529">Ethereum</option>
                        <option value="666,541,791,529">BNB</option>
                        <option value="xrp">Ripple</option>
                        <option value="doge">Dogecoin</option>
                        <option value="ada">Cardano</option>
                        <option value="Sol">Solana</option>
                        <option value="trx">TRON</option>
                        <option value="avax">Avalanche</option>
                        <option value="ltc">Litecoin</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                        <label class="" for="myChart1">Token Analizi</label>
                        <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        <script>
            function toggleMenu() {
                let toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
                let navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
                let main = document.querySelector('.main');
                toggle.classList.toggle('active');
                navigation.classList.toggle('active');
                main.classList.toggle('active');
            }
        </script>
        <script>
         const coincesit = document.getElementById('coincesit');
         coincesit.addEventListener('change',cointracker);
            function cointracker(){
                const label = coincesit.options[coincesit.selectedIndex].text;
                myChart1.data.datasets[0].label = label;
                console.log(myChart1.data.datasets[0].data = coincesit.value.split(','));
                myChart1.update();
            }
            const myChart1 = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart1'),
            config
            );
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the query style from other projects but couldn't implement it to my project perfectly I guess. I want my charts to get data from MySQL.

Comment: Could you please add the data you enter manually and the one which is added via your PHP code, to your question.

Comment: Try comparing the structure of `print json_encode($data);` with the static values which worked previously.